# Enterprise Architect Exports & Image positions

Tags: php, enterprise-architect

Exporting a diagram with EA is relative easy. The coordinates of the diagram are found in the XMI export; I use them to create a image map; but there's one problem; the coordinates aren't always on the right place. Is there somehow I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates in XMI are sometimes relative, and the extended section in an XMI is very tool specific, which could be challenging at times.

If you are creating an image map for publishing, I've used a slightly different approach. By generating a diagram only report from the model and then building a map from it.

Just my 2c